# Circular dependency using MVC in c# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, circular-dependency

I have 4 projects into my solution.

- sol-Model ( No reference )
- sol-Controller ( reference to Model )
- sol-View ( Reference to Controller AND Model )
- sol-Program ( Reference to View/Controller/Model )

My problem is: my model (or my controller no matter, the problem remains the same) has to contain some "Form Class" (from `sol-View`) and my controller has to load/showDialog() them during the execution.

But all my forms are contained into `sol-View` which is not referenced in `sol-Model` and `sol-Controller`. And I can't reference it due to circular dependency.

What is the proper solution to do that?

Comment: Do you have a reason to separate your views and controllers into separate projects?

Comment: Why not have just one project that has all three? I believe that is typically the way this is done.

Comment: Your views and controllers are best off being kept together, have a separate project for your model. Try not to over engineer it.

Comment: The view project is just for "testing" the functionnality. I will add my Controller and my Model into an other project ( an IE extension ) after. But if there is no way to do that ( maybe some trick with interface ? ) with separate project i will do one project :/

Comment: It's not a "model" if it contains form class information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `so-Model` has a dependency on `sol-View` for `Forms`, then:

1. Extract the `Forms` dependencies into a separate project that can be referenced by all projects.
2. Reduce complexity by keeping the Model, View, Controller classes in the same project.

Option 2 is the typical MVC approach and would probably be easier to manage. As the app grows, you can start extracting the dependencies into separate projects.

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly i found a method which respects circular mvc dependencies, so i accept Metro's answer ( anyway, I've finally regroup my projects ) but this is a way with interface. But it's very tedious.

**Controller project**

```
public interface IMyView
{
    void SetController(MyModelController controller);
    void showDialog();
    Label getLabel1();
    // etc.
}

public class MyModelController
{
    protected IMyView _myView;
    private MyModel _myModel;

    public MyModelController(IMyView view, MyModel mm)
    {
        _myView= view;
        _MyModel = mm;
        view.SetController(this);
    }

    public void myMethod()
    {
      // now i can interact with the view provided my functions are in IMyView
      _myView.showDialog();
      _myView.getLabel1(); // etc.
    }
}
```

**View project**

```
public partial class MyView : Form, IMyView
{
    private MyModelController _controller;

    public void SetController(MyModelController controller)
    {
        _controller = controller;
    }

    public void showDialog()
    {
         this.ShowDialog();
    }

    public Label getLabel1()
    {
        return this._label1;
    }
}
```

**INIT**

```
MyView view = new MyView();
MyModel model = new MyModel();
MyModelController controller = new MyModelController(view,model);
```